# Как преобразовать дату, введенную в текстовом формате, в миллисекунды?

Tags: веб-программирование, ruby

Написать приложение, которое позволяет превратить дату, введенную в текстовом формате, в миллисекунды (язык Ruby).  
Ломаю голову, ничего придумать не могу, помогите, извините, что не в тему...

Comment: Для начала можно посмотреть (исходный код), как этот разбор реализован в других языках или библиотеках.

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема. Вот как текущее время преобразовать:

    require 'date'
    
    p DateTime.now.strftime('%Q') # "1384526946523" (milliseconds)

Comment: @urasuper1994, если от вас действительно требуют, по факту, парсинга даты (а не найти встроенные инструменты языка):

1. Разбиваем дату на год, месяц, день и так далее.
2. Отнимаем от года 1970, а от месяца и дня по единице (отсчет стандартного timestamp ведется от первого января 1970 года).
3. Превращаем все по очереди в миллисекунды: Х секунд = Х * 1000 миллисекунд, Y минут - Y * 60000 миллисекунд и так далее.
4. Складываем.
5. Проверяем, что полученное значение в тысячу раз больше таймстампа для той же даты.
6. Не забываем использовать 64-битные числа или хотя бы флоаты для вычисления.

Comment: Вот только это все не работает корректно.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'time'

p Time.parse('2014-10-08 12:13:14.156789 +0400').to_f * 1000
```